# Can I somehow use different existingConnection in same entity DatabaseContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I need to use same entity DatabaseContext constructor for different connections (between sqlite and mysql). The connection string can changes (for both connections), so i can't use definied connectionString in App.config (or I need to change it somehow).

[Two DatabaseContexts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NL2v.png)

**UPDATE:**
Here's code from pic above where I use different entity DatabaseContext constructors. In comment of first constructor shown unworking code how I want to use it (different database connections in same constructor).

```
/// <summary>
    /// Sqlite database connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
    public DatabaseContext(string connectionString) : base(new SQLiteConnection() {ConnectionString = connectionString}, true)
    {
        //base.Configuration = new MySqlConnection();
        //base.Configuration = new SQLiteConnection() {ConnectionString = connectionString}, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// MySql database connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
    /// <param name="mock">Identifies mysql connect</param>
    public DatabaseContext(string connectionString, bool mock) : base(new MySqlConnection() {ConnectionString = connectionString}, true)
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you copy paste your code into your question using the code fences?

Comment: @Pavlos Hi, sorry, updated my post (the code was in picture above).